# C# language purpose of "override" abstract method

Tags: c#

Using C# for a while, I've just got curious about overriding abstract methods. I'm NOT asking "Why we have to override every abstract method?", but asking "Why we use `override` keyword on implementing abstract method?".

Abstract class were really useful when I had to provide the basic functionality of classes. Since Unity doesn't support C# 8.0 yet, the only choice to provide default method was to make abstract classes :(

```cs
public interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class A : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething() { }
}

// ----------------------------------

public abstract class Something
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
{

public class B : Something
{
    public override void DoSomething() { }  // WHY override to only this??
}
```

What I thought to be weird is, there is literally *nothing* to override in abstract method since there is no function body, just like interface method. Then why I should write `override` keyword? Is there any purpose for it? Or Was there any inevitable reason to do so?

Comment: Implementing interface != inheriting from abstract class.

Comment: Only one of the C# language designers (e.g. Anders Hejlsberg) could really answer this question - anything else will just be an opinion.

Comment: Because with `public override void DoSomething() { }` in `B` you are overwriting the definition of `DoSomething` in `Something` (that definition might by an abstract one, but it is overridden none the less)

Comment: I don't think the duplicate question is actually a duplicate, since that is specifically asking about redeclaring an abstract method in a derived abstract class.

Comment: One of the main purposes for wanting `override` *at all* is to prevent the danger of introducing a new method in the base class silently making a previously unique method in a derived class now suddenly be an implementation of that new method, with no compiler errors, if the names/parameters match.